# Blog Module for Sitecore 9

Tags: sxa, weblog

Installing WeBlog latest version with Sitecore 9 is breaking Sitecore instance. Are there any other blog module which can work with Sitecore 9 and SXA? Thank you,

Comment: We've just finished upgrading WeBlog to Sitecore 9 and made it work with SOLR. Doing some QA right now, and I will be checking in the upgraded code to GitHub in a few days for everybody to use. Please reach out for any questions.

Comment: Hi @NabilOrfali , Have you managed to upgrade the WeBlog module to be compatible with Sitecore 9?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can build a blog on top of **SXA**

I've created a step by step tutorial how to do it [**here**](https://alan-null.github.io/2017/12/sxa-blog)

Here are default renderings that can be used on blog.
[image]
[image]
[image]

To display posts on homepage you could use Page List or Search Results
[image]

If you need comments there are FB comments, Disqus

Screenshots come from [XA.Reference site](https://github.com/alan-null/XA.Reference/releases). If you are not sure how to configure them, install it and play.

Comment: How to create a folder structure (year/month) for blog posts under 'blog root'?

Comment: Read this section of my blog post. https://alan-null.github.io/2017/12/sxa-blog#blog-base-partial-design

Comment: When creating new blog posts under blog home, The content tree creates time and date folder structure. Is there a way to only create year and month only? I followed exact steps but content tree has four different folder before blog post entry (ex: 03 -> 05 -> 19 -> 34 -> blog post1)

Comment: https://alan-null.github.io/2017/12/sxa-blog#faq -> How I can change URL slug

Answer (score 4):

WeBlog is an open source repository so one solution for having a Sitecore 9 version of the WeBlog module is for you to fork it and update it to Sitecore 9. This will help you and also the community who already use WeBlog!

Otherwise, as Alan mentions, SXA is a great solution for this.